# Java Pointers -> Referring to video

Tags: java, pointers

Our university professor showed us this video in our computer science class last week. The language that we are working with is java (I am not sure about this for other languages)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pmWojisM_E

The video shows how if we have a int x and set it to 50, and then we create a new int y and set it to x, y and x will point to the same location. The question I have is that in java, doesn't it work differently for primitive data types? I understand that objects are all stored using pointers, but for primitive data types like int, char, etc, does it still use the same rules? By doing int x = 1; int y = x, will it just have x and y point to the same location, or will it create a new int stored in memory that is saved as y?

How about other languages (out of interest)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The video shows how if we have a int x and set it to 50, and then we create a new int y and set it to x, y and x will point to the same location.`

Not quite..it says `int*`, not `int`.

an `int*` refers to some location in memory where an `int` is stored. Languages like c and c++ allow you to directly read the address of a variable, and update the contents that are stored there.

```
// c and c++
int x = 5;
int* y = &x;
*y = 6;
printf("%d\n", x); // <-- will print 6
```

Java does not allow us to do this on primitive types. You described something like this:

```
// java
int x = 5;
int y = x;
y = 6;
System.out.println(x); // <-- will print 5
```

`x` will remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Wasn't sure if that * meant something important.

So would doing:
int x = 6;
int y = x;

be exactly the same (in terms of how the computer executes it) as:
int x = 6;
int y = 6;

Comment: @user2249516 yeah, the `*` is very important for this sort of thing.

Comment: @user2249516 yup -- they're just two different variables on the runtime stack that happen to have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

In java it will just allocate a new local variable, completely seperated from the 'original' `x`. What you do on `y` does not affect `x`, and vise versa.

Note that in C / C++, it is the same as declaring two variables of type `int` (and not `int*` / `int&`).

Every language I am aware of supports the value semantic, in order to get the reference semantic ("two variables are connected to each other") the language should support reference/pointer semantics for primitives.

Answer (score 0):

The video shows how pointers work in C language, not in Java.

In Java, as you mentionned in your post, primitive data types use a copy of the value, whereas object types use a copy of the reference to the object. Thus, changing the reference afterwards does not influence the first reference, but at the end of all the copies of this references is only one object. Changing is object effects all references, then.

Watch out when using String. Since this class uses the string constant pool, it is possible but not certain that string String str1 = "Hello world" and String str2 = str1 have a reference to the same string constant in memory.